# Trouble with Einstein coefficients - what is the meaning of the transition probability?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, probability, spectroscopy, absorption, photon-emission

Perhaps it seems to be a not very intelligent question, but I am unfortunately not able to understand what the probability per second that a molecule will absorb a photon is, as part of the theory of Einstein coefficients. For a noninteracting molecule with two energy levels $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ there are in the textbook „Laser Spectroscopy 1” by Wolfgang Demtröder given the following definitions:

The probability per second that a molecule will absorb a photon:

$\frac{dP_{12}}{dt}=B_{12}\cdotρ\left(ν\right)$

The probability that one molecule emits one induced photon per second:

$\frac{dP_{21}}{dt}=B_{21}\cdotρ\left(ν\right)$

The probability per second that a photon is spontaneously emitted by a molecule:

$\frac{dP_{21}^{spont}}{dt}=A_{21}$

Here, $B_{12}, B_{21}$ and $A_{21}$ are the corresponding Einstein coefficients for absorption, stimulated and spontaneous emission of a photon and $ρ\left(ν\right)$ is the spectral energy density of the radiation field.

On the other hand we can write like in the theory of reaction kinetics in chemistry differential equations for the relative number of molecules in the ground state and in the excited state:

$\frac{dn_{1}\left(t\right)}{dt}=-B_{12}\cdotρ\left(ν\right)\cdot n_{1}\left(t\right)+B_{21}\cdotρ\left(ν\right)\cdot n_{2}\left(t\right)+A_{21}\cdot n_{2}\left(t\right)$

$\frac{dn_{2}\left(t\right)}{dt}=+B_{12}\cdotρ\left(ν\right)\cdot n_{1}\left(t\right)-B_{21}\cdotρ\left(ν\right)\cdot n_{2}\left(t\right)-A_{21}\cdot n_{2}\left(t\right)$

where $n_{1}\left(t\right)=\frac{N_{1}\left(t\right)}{N}$ and $n_{2}\left(t\right)=\frac{N_{2}\left(t\right)}{N}$ are the relative numbers of molecules being in the ground or in the excited state, $N$ being the total number of molecules.

And from here the problem begins. When it comes to probabilities, I always try to imagine the statistical experiment. So, I'm trying to think that I have before me an ensemble of independent/noninteracting molecules. At the beginning the ensemble is always in the ground state. Then the molecules are irradiated with light and the stopwatch is started. I count and record the relative number of molecules that have been excited as a function of time. Intuitively, I would associate this relative number/probability with $P_{12}$ and its derrivative with $\frac{dP_{12}}{dt}$, but it is clear, that it is in this case rather $n_{2}\left(t\right)$ that was recorded. It is from the formulas $\frac{dP_{12}}{dt}=B_{12}\cdotρ\left(ν\right)$ and $\frac{dn_{2}\left(t\right)}{dt}=+B_{12}\cdotρ\left(ν\right)\cdot n_{1}\left(t\right)-B_{21}\cdotρ\left(ν\right)\cdot n_{2}\left(t\right)-A_{21}\cdot n_{2}\left(t\right)$ obvious that $P_{12}$ is not the same as $n_{2}\left(t\right)$. And here is my problem: what is $P_{12}$ and its derivative and what would the corresponding statistical experiment look like? Please help me to understand correctly the probability per second that a molecule will absorb a photon.

Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you have $N$ atoms in a particular state at $t=0$, then 1 second later the three radiative processes will have contributed to changing that number by an amount $dN$, where $dN =-A_{21}N$ for spontaneous emission and so on. $dN/N$ for a process will then be a dimensionless probability of that process occuring in a second for any molecule.

In your example, considering the ground state, then $dN = n2(t) - n_1(t)$.

Maybe it's easier to understand if you write the rate of change of $N$ as $dN/dt = N dP/dt$ ? i.e. Discuss the rate at which molecules enter or leave a particular state which is just the number of molecules multiplied by the probability per second of a process occurring.